# Palindrome in Python operating on strings only

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I am trying to write a program in Python which will detect that the word given by a user is a palindrome or not.

Here is my code - I operate only on strings - my solution is totally different that other which I have seen here or anywhere, thus I would like you - StactOverFlow users ;) - to check its correctness.

I needn't say that I am not a pro, having rather basic knowledge.
However, I would be glad if anyone spend their time and give me some feedback.

```
# a palindrome
string = input('word: ')
if(len(string) % 2 != 0):
  left = string.lower()[0:int((len(string)-1)/2)]
  right = string.lower()[int((len(string)-1)/2 + 1): ]
  if left == right[::-1]:
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(string.lower()))
  else:
    print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(string))
else:
  left = string.lower()[0:int((len(string)/2))]
  right = string.lower()[int(len(string)/2):]
  if left == right[::-1]:
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(string.lower()))
  else:
    print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(string.lower()))
```

Comment: Are you asking if this code works? If that's the case, I'm sure you can compile it on your own. Otherwise, you may be looking for code review, which might be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I wrote this code so it is free from syntax errors and it works in this sense. The question is: if the logic behind this is correct.

Comment: It's way more complex than it needs to be...

Comment: You mean that this is a correct solution, i. e. the idea itself? I guess it can be done in an easier way, but even though this one is more complex, it is correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a palindrome just check if the reverse string is equal to the original one

```
palindromes_test = ['ABCDCBA','EVE','ABCABC']

print ([v for v in palindromes_test if (v == (v[::-1]))])
```

output

```
 ['ABCDCBA', 'EVE']
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your attention ;) No one of you wrote explicitly that this is correct, but using these three 'test strings' give me the same results as in the first answer. I know that it is overcomplicate - thanks to you ;) However, at the beginning it is wonderful when a code works. So, thanks guys once again, I'll accept both answers as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you get a oneliner that prints out the palindromes:**

```
print ([v for v in palindromes_test if (len(v) % 2 == 0 and v[0:len(v)//2] == v[len(v)//2:][::-1]) or (len(v) % 2 != 0 and v[0:len(v)//2] == v[len(v)//2+1:][::-1])])
```

Otherwise:

```
palindromes_test = ['ABCDCBA','EVE','ABCABC']

for elem in palindromes_test:
    if len(elem) % 2 == 0 and elem[0:len(elem)//2] == elem[len(elem)//2:][::-1]:
        print ("%s palindrome" % elem)
    elif len(elem) % 2 != 0 and elem[0:len(elem)//2] == elem[len(elem)//2+1:][::-1]:
        print ("%s palindrome" % elem)
    else:
        print ("%s not palindrome" % elem)
```

Output:

```
ABCDCBA palindrome
EVE palindrome
ABCABC not palindrome
```

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing to write the whole solution in only one line ;) 
For your 'test strings' my solution works as yours, I guess this indicates that my complex code is correct.

Comment: Ahaha always better to start by writting multiline codes. That's how you understand the underlying logic. It my answer helped, still, you can validate it ;) (gray tick top left of the answer)

Comment: overcomplicated i think :)

Comment: Lol that's funny. Did you copy past my code in your answer?! At least you did with the example sequences ahaha.

Comment: Good example set ! Bad answer haha

Comment: That's not nice to use your 2k+ reput privileges to edit posts from your 10 years old best friendship IRL. Bad practice dude.